# php help understand what this line does, or translate to C#

Tags: php

```
if (strrpos($_POST['security_data'], $OrderReference) === false || 
    md5($_POST['security_data'] . $sekey) != $_POST['security_hash']) 
{ 
  return; 
}
```

I don't understand why is strrpos in there and === "3 equals"
and what is the dot "." doing in `$_POST['security_data'] . $sekey`

Thank You

Comment: I thought Cuck Norris would be the *only one* to understand the most egregious php code samples...

Comment: `strrpos($_POST['security_data'], $OrderReference) === false`
will be true if `$_POST['security_data']` doesn't contain `$OrderReference`. I don't know why strrpos, which searches backwards, is used rather than strpos, which searches forwards and would seem the more obvious call to make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a translation to C#:

```
string hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Request.Form["security_data"] + sekey);    
if (!Request.Form["security_data"].Contains(OrderReference) 
    || hash != Request.Form["security_hash"])
{
     return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @FloydThreepwood, I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Also I think you needed one `!` for doesn't contain

Answer (score 6):

`strrpos` returns the position of the substring.

```
echo strrpos("Hello", "e"); // outputs `1`
```

---

`.` is concatenation.

```
echo "Hello "."There"; // outputs: 'Hello There'
```

---

`===` checks type as well as equality.

```
var_dump(1 == true); // true
var_dump(1 === true); // false
```

Answer (score 3):

- `strrpos` returns `false` if the string isn't found (don't know which string in which, but the docs will tell you)
- `===` compares type as well instead of just value. This is done so php doesn't to any casting, for example `0 == false` (`0` represents `false` in php as well) but `0 !== false` as `0` isn't the same type as `false`.
- the `.` is the concat operator in php.

Answer (score 3):

strrpos is "return position of substring within a string, starting from the right (end) side". `===` is the PHP strict comparison, which compares type AND value. The strpos functions **CAN** return a legitimate `0` as a position, which is the very start of the string. But `0` evalutes to boolean FALSE in PHP, so the `===` check ensures that you're looing at a real false (strrpos found nothing) and not just "strrpos found string at position zero".

Answer (score 3):

The dot (.) connects between 2 strings, and the 3 equals checks if the returned value is in the same type as what it compared to

Answer (score 3):

If the contents of the variable `$OrderReference` are not found in the POST variable `security_data`, or the MD5 hash of the POST variable `security_data`, concatenated with (that's the `.` operator in PHP) the variable `$sekey` isn't equal to `security_hash`, return from the function.

`===` is used to ensure that the return from `strrpos()` is the boolean `FALSE` rather than the possible valid return value of `0`. `===` is for strict type comparison.